# Skype and Gtalk crash whenever I make a call

Tags: windows-7, laptop, skype, google-talk

Skype crashes and ends up crashing all the other applications. Gtalk works fine except when i make a call. This happens on both of my laptops. Anyone know what the reason could be? I haven't been able to use Skype for months now.

Answer (score 0):

Check with other applications which would use the microphone or the camera.

It could be crashing because of a driver issue in the sound card or the webcam.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue with non enough RAM available. When it is making a call, it uses more RAM. I would monitor the processes and see if there's a memory leak. Have you already tried removing and re-installing the applications? It could also be driver issues for the microphone or camera as the other answer says. You should also try it in Safe-Mode and see if it works, if so then it may be some application that starts up that's interfering.